# 1st Law of Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I am unable to understand how the writer says about horizontal components.Although in following diagram only Vertical components and Hypotenuse are given:

[image]

This is  the framework of issoceles triangle whose hypotenuses(6N,6N) and perpendiculars(P,5N) are given...but in answer of the question horizontal components are mentioned .How can we calculate Horizontal components?

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the diagram as depicting four different forces applied to a particle. There are two forces applied at angles of 30° to either side of the horizontal and two forces applied perpendicularly to the horizontal. The forces applied at angles of 30° can be thought of as having vertical and horizontal components that tell you how the forces act in those directions. These can be found as the legs of the right triangle with the force as the hypotenuse. Thus, the horizontal (x) components and the vertical (y) components can be found with

$$F_x = F*cos(θ)$$ and 
$$F_y = F*sin(θ)$$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think about hypotenuses. Just see it as four different forces.

And then think of them as ropes pulling in a boat. One man at each rope pulling in a boat in the middle. The two 30 degree forces are therefore making the boat go rightwards *and* upwards or downwards (if they were alone) - which together is an angled direction.

- In question a), all the pulls upwards balance out all pulls downwards. The boat thus only continues to the right because the two 30 degree forces both pull a bit to the right as well (the horizontal components don't cancel out).
- In question b), the guy on top pulls too hard. That will make the boat float towards him, since he pulls harder than the others. There is therefore a net vertical force in this case. There is *still* the motion to the right as well. We have *both* horizontal and vertical motions in this case, which in total givse an angled direction of the motion.

Comment: ,please tell , Do you take into account the  resolution of  6N forces into components while solving the problem?When you speak about horizontal components,you meant the horizontal component of 6N force that has derived after resolution of this force?

Comment: @M.NaeemAhmad What do you mean by "resolution"? As the answer describes, a force pulling at an angle can indeed be thought of as a pull sideways (horizontally) and a pull upwards (vertically).

Comment: @ Steeven  I meant by Resoution:''A process by which vector is resolved into two rectangular components along x &y axes respectively...

Comment: @M.NareemAhmad Thank you, then the answer is yes. I will look at this problem in two parts: horizontal motion and vertical motion. All horizontal forces and horizontal force components have effect in the horizontal direction only, and all vertical ones in the vertical direction only. Then you can separately in two steps find out if there is any horizontal and any vertical acceleration by finding out if the horizontal and vertical forces and components in total are balanced.